# WAN works but LAN does not

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, lan

I have a TP-LINK router running the newest firmware (firmware version: 4.7.11 Build 101102 Rel.60376n, hardware version: WR340G v3 081520C2). It has a cable connected from the ISP to the WAN port and broadcasts the Internet via WiFi in my house. I have a few computers and smartphones that use it.

After a few hours of work the LAN network stops working (the devices don't see each other, on a wireless connection). However, the Internet still works. I cannot use a wired connection as all of my devices are laptops or smartphones and it will be highly inconvenient.

When I try to enter the router configuration page, it does not respond. Even `ping 192.168.1.1` does not work (waiting time exceeded). Pings to other devices do not work either.

Network configuration (on a host that I'm working right now):

```
IPv4 address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.100
Subnet mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
Default gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1
```

The LAN network "works" for a few hours after I reboot the router by switching the power off and on.

Is there anything I could try other than replacing the device with a new one?

Comment: Did you check for firmware updates for the router? Or search to see if this is a common issue with this router model?

Comment: Yes, before I asked this question I had installed the newest firmware from http://www.tp-link.com.pl/support/download/?model=TL-WR340G&version=V2#tbl_b I could not find any similar issues in the web.

Comment: You should update your question with that information so others know what you've done without having to ask.

Comment: when LAN stops do you mean Wi-Fi or Wired connection? If only Wireless you should connect PC to it using network cable and check the settings.

Comment: Have you also reset it to default via software AND the hardware button it has? Sometimes they just get stuck in a bad state...

I checked and it is not listed as supported by dd-wrt so that option is unfortunately not available.

Comment: Bah edit timed out!

Also consider trying an OLDER firmware as I have seen this solve the problem many times before (sometimes the manufacturer gets lazy with different hardware versions and bugs crop up).

Answer (score 0):

Heat can make a failing device worse.  An easy test is to open the case (if possible), blow out any dust and use a regular house fan to cool it.

If that works, I would suggest replacing the unit soon. Sometimes the fan will buy a little time though.

Comment: I have also seen devices fail because of low temperatures. Utah is fun like that!